# Adding space and punctuation into generate character

Tags: python

I'm creating a word generate from a starting number. I'm stuck with the last function which require a bit logic to add space and punctuation in the character generate to create a sentence. And I don't know how to work this out. Please help

````
def number_generator(start_number, amount):
    x = start_number
    x = x * (pow(x, 2) * 3) / 2
    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = m.sqrt(x)
        value = x
        number_binder(x, amount)
    else:
        x = pow(x, 3) / 16
        value = x
        number_binder(x, amount)
    return value

def number_binder(x, amount):
    character = ''
    character_number = (x % 23) + 97
    character += chr(int(character_number))
    print(str(character), end='')
    sentence_creator(x, amount)
    return character

def sentence_creator(x, amount):
    for i in range(amount):
        if x % 3 == 0:
            print(character + " ", end='')
        elif x % 40 == 0:
            print(character + ". ", end='')
        number_generator(x, amount)''```


I tried google and AI but can't not get any help with this
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.